# iPhone X full screen issue

Tags: autolayout, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

Today I've installed **Xcode 9** and build my app for **iPhone x**. but the upper and bottom area showing black like the scenarios we met couple of years ago for iPhone 5 when screen switched to 3.5 to 4.

How simply we can fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please refer this link "https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925684/2776795" may be help you

Comment: @Sunil did you resolved an issue? I am having same, we are not using constraints as well.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna yes I have fixed this by adding launch image of 1125*2436px

Comment: @SunilTarge Do you have launch image or launch storyboard in your project?

Comment: @TejasArdeshna yes I have launch storyboard.

Comment: @SunilTarge we are not using launch storyboard and launch images as well. So that won't apply on my prj.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna Then you can just add iPhone X portrait image in Asset.xcassets > LaunchImage.

Comment: Yes but that caused layout issues in the storyboard. because we are not using constraints.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna I also have same issue. i am not using constraints. Did you resolved this issue..?? than please advise me to do the same.

Comment: @Mohit From April 1st even you can't upload your app if there is no launch screen. Mean ultimately end of zoom mode apps.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna Thanks for your replay. I am using launch screen images but not using auto layout constraints in any views. Now when i put launch screen image for iPhone x my screen layout is not showing properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a **safe area**.

> For apps with custom layouts, supporting iPhone X should also be
>   relatively easy, especially if your app uses Auto Layout and adheres
>   to safe area and margin layout guides.

Read more: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

I am also same issue. I used safe area Layout also. But above solution not support for me . I got solution from below link.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/get-your-apps-ready-for-iphone-x/

This below point helped for me to resolve that solution.

**Ensure your app uses a Launch Screen storyboard (not Launch images).**

Comment: Got help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46184998/1023074) answer also.

Comment: I found that a safe area did not help me without also setting up a launch screen.