# Screen size issue with ionic on iPhone X

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, iphone-x

I'm trying to export my app in **ionic 3**. But when I launch in the iPhone X emulator, the screen have 2 empty espaces in the top and bottom (screen problem?).

Anyone help to adapt the resolution to iPhone X resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone X full screen issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190975/iphone-x-full-screen-issue)

Comment: More info at:
http://blog.ionic.io/updates-for-all-ionic-angular-3-7-and-more/

Answer (score 6):

In order to remove that empty spaces you can add `viewport-fit=cover`to your meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content-type="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Comment: what's the css media query for a landscape hold iPhone X with viewport-fit=cover enabled?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with the Titanium SDK. The issue is that you need to provide the correct launch-screens that adapt the new screen-sizes: -

- Portrait: 1125x2436
- Landscape: 2436x1125

For Titanium, it was just solved by adjusting the build-script to detect and package the launch-screens, so probably the Ionic team will do something similar soon!

For native Xcode, the issue can be the same and is resolved by placing the correct images into the Asset-Catalog:

[image: Xcode Asset Catalog for iPhone X]

Answer (score 2):

Add proper launch images for iphone x [Launch image adding help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191522/how-to-add-iphonex-launch-image)

Then follow these

For a manual fix to an existing cordova project

UI interface issue

Add this to your info.plist file. Fixing the launch image is a separate issue

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
```

Set viewport-fit=cover in the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

[More help](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13273)

Comment: This worked for me; however, running ionic prepare removes the `UILaunchStoryboardName` from the info.plist. Any advise? Here is my question with the full details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197628/uilaunchstoryboardname-and-its-value-cdvlaunchscreen-is-being-removed-by-ionic

Comment: same Issue , it removes the UILaunchStoryboardName from the info.plist

Answer (score 2):

First, add `viewport-fit=cover` into `index.html` meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

then, The statusbar plugin PR has been merged in. Please install the latest stable version of the cordova statusbar.

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```

Next, add this CSS in your src/app/app.scss:

```
<style>
.ios.cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) {
  height: calc(44px + constant(safe-area-inset-top));
}


.ios.cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) > * {
  margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
}

div.tab-nav.tabs {
  height: calc(49px + constant(safe-area-inset-bottom));
}

ion-content.padding.scroll-content.ionic-scroll.has-header.has-tabs {
  top: calc(64px + constant(safe-area-inset-top));
}
</style>
```

last one,
add a 1125 × 2436 size splash screen for iphone X ,give path of it in `config.xml`

```
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@3x~iphone.png" width="1125" height="2436"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugin statusbar is updated to work for iPhoneX in 2.3.0 Please check the [release notes](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/10/plugins-release.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, add viewport-fit=cover into index.html meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">`

Second add Status bar plugin

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git