# UILaunchStoryboardName and it's value CDVLaunchScreen is being removed by ionic prepare command

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, iphone-x

I have a Ionic Cordova project and am trying to make sure that it is fullscreen on iPhone X and newer phones. I have gone to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator) and everything works fine until I run `ionic prepare` and it removes `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key><string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>` from the .plist file. I tried adding this:

```
"config_munge": {
"files": {
  "*-Info.plist": {
    "parents": {
      "UILaunchStoryboardName": [
        {
          "xml": "<string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>",
          "count": 1
        }
      ],
```

to my ios.json and that doesn't help. I also tried this in my config.xml file:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="UILaunchStoryboardName" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
    </config-file>
```

And that doesn't help. If I set it in both the `Info > Custom iOS Target Properties` and set the `General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File` to `CDVLaunchScreen` but all that always gets overwritten with the next `ionic prepare` command. How do I prevent that from being overwritten?

P.S. my Cordova version is 8.1.2 and iOS is engine is 5.0.0. Also, if it makes a difference, here are my plugins:

- cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support 1.6.2 "Cordova CocoaPods Dependency Support"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
  1.3.4 "Whitelist"
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.2-dev "Cordova WKWebView Engine" cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix 0.1.0 "WKWebView XHR Fix"
- cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.1 "Diagnostic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have this in the config.xml file and so it was removing it in `cordova prepare`:

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />
```

Comment: Same issue , the solution above didn't worked for me . :(