# iOS - resize view layer to fill iPhone X Max background

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerlayer, safearealayoutguide

I've following https://stackoverflow.com/a/46337372/2139691 in order to have a view to fill the background.
So I use a View called myview with a blue background, but when I add a video layer I have bad results.

```
class MovViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    @IBOutlet weak var myview: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video_fondo", ofType: "mp4")
        let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        playerLayer.frame = myview.bounds
        myview.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
        player.play()

    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get it using:

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
```

Answer (score 1):

The player layer background is transparent by default. Try setting a background color on the player layer if you want to hide the blue view behind.

```swift
playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```