# Xcode 11 Safe Area Does Not Go FullScreen

Tags: swift, xcode

Since I am using Xcode 11 I am having problems with the Safe Area. My App is an ArKit- App that uses an ARSCNView. after upgrading to Xcode 11 the safe Are doesn't allow me to display it full screen anymore. Actually all the views in all ViewControllers can't be displayed in full screen. I really don't know where to start. Did anyone experience this kind of behavior?

Thanks!

Edit:
I unchecked all the necessary boxes I hope. The behavior I still get is this:

[Storyboard Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59LJZ.png)

[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXAe4.png)

[Live View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw9pF.jpg)

There seems to be a view underneath. But I never added one and the inspector doesn't show. This changed with xcode11.

Comment: Read this (safe area does not mean full screen) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Answer (score 2):

I just found out what happened to my ViewControllers. I am checking for internet connection with a LaunchViewController. The segue from this controller to the next one did not specify "full screen". I still don't know why I have to explicitly tell the segue to do so in Xcode 11. But in the end that solved my problem.

Thank you

Comment: Hey thanks Aknitt. I did help. In my case I had to setup full screen for my Modally segue(to my navigation controller). To setup full screen, this is what you do. Click the segue and go to Attributes Inspector--> Presentation-->Full Screen.

Answer (score 0):

The Safe Area is used as a reference for constraints for views and objects that you want the user to be able to interact with. It is used as a guide during the layout of objects on the screen. If you want to take advantage of the entire screen, constrain your views to the superview (basically the main view of the view controller). This is handy for displaying things like backgrounds on the entire view. Take a look at Apple's human interface guidelines for more info:

[Apple's Human Interface Guidelines: Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)

Similar Question:

[iPhone X - Safe Area does not achieve full-screen experience?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275330/iphone-x-safe-area-does-not-achieve-full-screen-experience)