# White area on top and bottom of iphone x when using launch image

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

**EDIT:**

**This question is NOT a duplicate of this:** [How to Add iPhoneX Launch Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191522/how-to-add-iphonex-launch-image)

**I have gone through the question there and all answers, and they do NOT address my issue!**

I'm using launch images (***not launch screen***) for an iOS app, and have added a  1125 x 2436 pixel launch image for iPhone X. Problem is, when the app runs, the launch image isn't completely full screen, and the top and bottom white area is still visible. How can I make the launch image *fully* full screen ?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the image is `Aspect Fill` and not `Aspect Fit`

Comment: Already done that.

Comment: Can we see what your constraints are?