# SwiftUI how to adjust different screen sizes (height)

Tags: swiftui, autoresize

there is the possibility with swiftui to match the different sizes iphones (7 / 8 /Xs /iphone 11....) ?

i am currently learning swiftui and i came across a problem.
If I leave the screen like this, the screen of the new iPhone is not nice.
I am considering whether to do the type of responsive at swiftui that the program fits in with the size of the picture.
but how ?
sorry i am not fit in english:::

this is the code

```
var w = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let h = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

struct PrayTimeView: View {


let prayTimes = Bundle.main.decode("time1.json")
var manager = LocalNotificationManager()


var body: some View {

    VStack {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Image("Prayer")
                .resizable()
                .overlay(ImageOverlay(items: prayTimes))

                .frame( height: h < 700 ? 210 : 220)

            HStack{
                Rectangle().fill(Color("Bg"))
                    .overlay(
                        VStack{
                            Text(Date().DDMMYYYY)
                                .font(h < 700 ? .headline : .title)
                                //.fontWeight(h < 700 ? .bold : .regular)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            Text(Date().DDMMYYYYIslamic)
                                .font(h < 700 ? .headline : .title)
                                //.fontWeight(h < 700 ? .bold : .regular)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                )

            }
            .frame(height: h < 700 ? 45 : 80)
        }

        Spacer()
        VStack{
            GeometryReader {_ in

                VStack{

                    timeView(self.prayTimes)
                }
            }
        }
    }.modifier(CustomMudifier())
        .navigationBarTitle("Gebet")

}
}


struct PrayTimeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    PrayTimeView()
}
}



struct ourView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var share : Share


@State var onN = false{

    didSet{
        share.isOn = onN
        if onN{
            print("ON")
            //set notifications

            let manager = LocalNotificationManager()


            // manager.sheduleForDay(item : item )
            manager.scheduleForAll(items: items)

        }
        else{
            print("off")
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(onN, forKey: "on")
    }
}
var items: [PrayTime]
var item: PrayTime



var body: some View {

    let bonN = Binding<Bool>(get: {self.onN}, set:{self.onN = $0})
    return

        GeometryReader{ geo in
        VStack {
            Toggle(" Notifications On", isOn: bonN)
                .frame(height:20)
            List{

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Fajr")
                        .fontWeight(self.share.currentPrayerIndex == 0 ? .heavy : .regular)

                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.fajr)
                    Image(systemName: "speaker")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                    )

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Sunrise")

                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.sunrise)
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                )

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Dhuhr")

                        .fontWeight(self.share.currentPrayerIndex == 1 ? .heavy : .regular)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.dhuhr)
                    Image(systemName: "speaker")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                )

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Asr")

                        .fontWeight(self.share.currentPrayerIndex == 2 ? .heavy : .regular)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.asr)
                    Image(systemName: "speaker")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                )

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Maghrib")

                        .fontWeight(self.share.currentPrayerIndex == 3 ? .heavy : .regular)

                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.maghrib)
                    Image(systemName: "speaker")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                )

                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).frame(height: (geo.size.height - 50)/8)
                    .overlay(
                HStack{
                    Text("Isha")

                        .fontWeight(self.share.currentPrayerIndex == 4 ? .heavy : .regular)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.item.isha)
                    Image(systemName: "speaker")
                        .padding(.vertical, h < 700 ? 0 : 17)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                )
            }
            .disabled(w < 350 ? false : true)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
}

        .onAppear{

            self.onN = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "on")
    }

}
}


func timeView(_ items: [PrayTime]) -> AnyView {
    let date = Date()
    let day = date.day + "-" + date.month

for item in items{
    if (item.id == day) {

        return(AnyView(ourView(items: items, item: item)))
    }
}
return AnyView(Text("Nothing Found. Please update to resolve."))
}


struct CountDownView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var share: Share

var items:[PrayTime]

var manager = LocalNotificationManager()

@State var interval : Int = 0

let prayers = ["Fajr","Dhuhr","Asr","Maghrib","Isha"]

@State var currentPrayerIndex = 0

var timerText : String {
    let dateForm = DateComponentsFormatter()
    dateForm.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    dateForm.unitsStyle = .positional
    dateForm.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second ]
    return dateForm.string(from: TimeInterval(interval)) ?? "00:00"
}

@State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()


var body: some View {

    HStack{
        Text("(-\(timerText))").font(Font.title.monospacedDigit()).bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        // .frame(width:150)
        Text(prayers[currentPrayerIndex])
            .font(h < 700 ? .title : .largeTitle).bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .onAppear{self.interval = self.countdownTimer(items: self.items)

    }

    .onReceive(timer) { time in
        self.interval -= 1
        if self.interval == 1 {
            self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            Sounds.playSoundsLocal(soundfile: "cbcd8d249dcc.mp3")


            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(5)){
                self.interval = self.countdownTimer(items: self.items)
                self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
            }
        }
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in

        self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in

        self.interval = self.countdownTimer(items: self.items)
        self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

        if self.share.isOn{
            self.manager.scheduleForAll(items: self.items)
        }
    }
}



func countdownTimer(items: [PrayTime]) -> Int {

    let date = Date()
    let day = date.day + "-" + date.month

    for item in items{

        if (item.id == day) {


            let notifTimeFajr = date.createDateFromJsonIdAndTime(dateStrTime: item.fajr, dayAndMonthStringJsonId: item.id) ?? Date()
            let notifTimeDhuhr = date.createDateFromJsonIdAndTime(dateStrTime: item.dhuhr, dayAndMonthStringJsonId: item.id) ?? Date()
            let notifTimeAsr = date.createDateFromJsonIdAndTime(dateStrTime: item.asr, dayAndMonthStringJsonId: item.id) ?? Date()
            let notifTimemAghrib = date.createDateFromJsonIdAndTime(dateStrTime: item.maghrib, dayAndMonthStringJsonId: item.id) ?? Date()
            let notifTimeIsha = date.createDateFromJsonIdAndTime(dateStrTime: item.isha, dayAndMonthStringJsonId: item.id) ?? Date()

            let dayPrayerTimesArray = [notifTimeFajr,notifTimeDhuhr,notifTimeAsr,notifTimemAghrib,notifTimeIsha]

            for i in 0..<dayPrayerTimesArray.count{
                if dayPrayerTimesArray[i] > Date(){
                    interval = Int(dayPrayerTimesArray[i].timeIntervalSince(Date()))
                    currentPrayerIndex = i
                    share.currentPrayerIndex = i
                    return interval
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return 0
}//end countdown function

}

struct ImageOverlay: View {


var items:[PrayTime]
@State var date = Date()
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        VStack {
            Text("\(timeString(date: date))").bold()

                .onAppear(perform: {let _ = self.updateTimer

                })
                .font(h < 700 ? .title : .largeTitle)
                .padding(6)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        VStack{

            CountDownView(items: items)

        }
    }
}

var timeFormat: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    return formatter
}
func timeString(date: Date) -> String {
    let time = timeFormat.string(from: date)
    return time
}
var updateTimer: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true,
                         block: {_ in
                            self.date = Date()
    })
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Just avoid hard-coding for UI element sizes and allow them adjust to screen automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by i am new in swiftui?

Comment: maybe an example, then i can get an idea of ​​that

Comment: you could use a geometry reader.

Comment: hi Rayan , i tray with geometry reader but i dont see any difference

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem like a SwiftUI problem. If your screen on iPhone X or later is cut like an iPhone 8 -with old home button- (as it looks in your screenshot) try to check and adapt your Launch Image (1125×2436 px iPhone X) if you have a `LaunchImage.launchimage` in `Assets.xcassets` (recommended) or reset your constraints in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. 
Launch Image affects the display. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843347/5941807).

Comment: i try it , und i tell you