# My app is not fullscreen on iPhoneX

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

on iPhoneX simulator my app is not fullscreen (see screenshot).

Do you have an idea why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please search before posting. This has already been asked and answered several times in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Please refer this link - "https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925684/2776795" may be it's help you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the problem. 
I had to add a launch image with iPhoneX sizes, which is 1125×2436.

I replace all Default images by a LaunchScreen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use lauchimage, you need assign new lauchimage for iPhoneX.