# Navigation Bar issue in iPhone X?

Tags: xcode, ios11, iphone-x

When I am running the project in iPhone X is getting black space above navigation bar as shown, not getting the color as same.

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: If you're using the LaunchImage in your application, then add the one for iPhone X with the size 1125x2436

Comment: Maybe you added the constraints for the status bar manually. It seems that the navigation bar is 22 points away from the safe area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are not using storyboard for launch screen.

There are two options to fix this.

1. Use storyboard as LaunchScreen.
2. If you are using Launch Image Source for launch screen add launch screen image for iPhoneX.

[image]

Comment: Please refer this link "https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925684/2776795"