# Change height of frame for iPhone X

Tags: objective-c, iphone-x

I want to change height of screen in order to support iPhone x. Currently when i run my app in simulator of iPhone X the height of bounds is 568.
The following line returns 568

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

Comment: on iphone x simulator did you see black bars on top and bottom??

Comment: yes i can see black black bars on top and bottom

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator

Comment: You need to provide the properly sized launch image for iphone x first then `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` will give you correct value.

Comment: Did you add Default image for iPhone X?

Comment: Hi @Bilal i added launch screen according to iPhone x. But the width is being taken of 320.

Answer (score 0):

This happen when you don't add Default image for iPhone X.

Add screenshot of iPhone X of size 1125px × 2436px and try again.

[Refer here for the default image sizes](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)