# Scale background image to iPhone 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, iphone-x

I'm using Swift 4, XCode 9. I have an iOS application which has a background image which was set using storyboard. The actual storyboard file is viewed from the frame of reference of an iPhone SE. However, I've never had a problem with the image scaling to bigger phone sizes, except now for iPhone 10. It won't fill the whole screen. How can I fix this? The background is displayed through an image view. I've tried changing the height of the image view both via story board and programmatically with no luck. Again, this only is a problem on iPhone 10.

EDIT: I've somewhat fixed this problem by adding a specific iPhone X Launch Image, but now my components are all shifted to the left

[image]

Comment: "How can I fix this?"  Fix what!?  You don't show a single line of code or a screnshot.

Comment: As you can [**see**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231731/4061501), iPhone X resolution is 1125px x 2436px. I think you have to set specific image programatically.

Comment: What's `UIImageView`'s current `contentMode `?

Comment: It is currently scaleToFill, I’ve tried others with no luck

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps you should be careful.

**Step 1: Choose the device iPhone X in Interface builder.**
[image]

**Step 2: Add a full image to the ViewController.**
[image]

**Step 3: Add constraints (Should be all Zero) by selecting the bottom menu.**
[image]

We all set. If you start adding from iPhone X or later devices, it will automatically adjust the bottom, top, left and right constraints accordingly all the previous devices.

**NB:** While we adding manual constraints, be aware that the **SafeAreaLayout** has the first priority than the manual constraints.

**Another method** (You can use either one depends upon your interest)

Provide leading, trialing, top and bottom constraints to the background image. Then select the bottom constrain, and from the size inspector choose the *first item* as **Superview**

[image]

[image]

I believe this will help somebody.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone X has a different screen size of 375 × 812 points (1125×2436 pixels). The iPhone X's aspect ratio is approximately 9:19.5 
So it is different. Here is Apple's official guide which tells you how to handle images.  https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Please show us some code or image so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: Did you give constraints properly? Did you set them up first?

Comment: No constraints, everything centers fine on all other devices. And, before adding this launch image, when I had my original problem, the components were all centered fine

Comment: Without constraints your views won't be properly placed. Can you tell us how you have added your imageview? And the orange color gradient is the image view you are talking about right?

Comment: This was my first iOS app I made years ago, so I literally just placed an image view on the storyboard view controller, sized it to cover the whole view (statically) within interface builder, and that was that. I’ve never had a problem with it scaling on new devices over the years until now. I’m hesitant to go through the entire project and add constraints just for iPhone 10 because it seems there should be a simpler more straightforward answer.

Comment: And yes the gradient is the image I’m referring to

Comment: The approach which you had taken is incorrect. It will just take an hour or so to apply constraints to your view. Without constraints, it won't be properly placed.

Comment: how is it that everything is centered perfectly on all other devices, and even on iPhone 10 when I remove the iPhone 10 launch image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164476/discussion-between-rizwan-ahmed-and-goat).