# How to set Safe Area layout in iPhone x

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, safearealayoutguide

I am developing Xamarin forms app and my app seems with safe area set in top. But need to ignore it.

**Current scenario:**

[image]

**Excepted scenario:**

[image]

I have googled regarding this and got below link, tried out as mentioned in below links and nothing worked.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104945/iphone-x-and-safe-margins-with-xamarin-forms
https://blog.xamarin.com/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/

But didn’t know how to access **SetPrefersLargeTitles** under Xamarin forms content page in below line mentioned in above link.

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetPrefersLargeTitles(true);
```

After set safe area as true output come as below,
[image]

Please help me to resolve this.

Regards,
Cheran

Comment: go to top constraint and make second constraint superview.Top

Answer (score 8):

You can do it from XAML like this

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```

Comment: I have tried but this seems padding set for parent layout and have updated output image in above query itself.

Answer (score 4):

Please Refer to [Making iOS 11 Even Easier with Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/)

We use [Platform-Specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/) to implement it.

#### Before iOS 11

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
```

#### iOS 11 or newer

```
var safeInsets  = On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
safeInsets.Left = 24;
this.Padding = safeInsets;
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. My issue related to below link and used as mentioned in link then resolved.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator

Comment: Perfect this is what I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to create or configure LaunchScreend.storyboard.

Use this [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TailwindTraders-Mobile/blob/ae084431a5f6fcd4d6d74a8095ddfa39c0b4d0cf/Source/TailwindTraders.Mobile/TailwindTraders.Mobile.iOS/Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard), change **splash_screen** for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Go to top constraint and make second Item constraint superview.Top

Answer (score 0):

```
public ItemsPage() {
    InitializeComponent();

    On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS> ().SetUseSafeArea(true);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Please do not post "raw" code snippets as answers to questions. Please add at least some explaination.