# Set Background Image Including Unsafe Area Programatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, safearealayoutguide

Is it possible to have a background image extend into the unsafe areas?  I tried the following to set a background image to the Super View and it doesn't work.

```
// viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up background image
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: super.view.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "SpaceBackground")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

}
```

[This approach uses auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator).

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing up because of the Navigation Controller.  Once that is hidden the image covers unsafe background area also.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
```