# How can I use Xcode / Simulator to create compatible iPhone 3rd Generation Screenshots from cordova 8 app

Tags: ios, cordova, screenshot, iphone-xs-max

I have fully working app for iOS in Xcode but I don't know how to generate the 3rd Generation Screenshots for the iPhone Xs Max or Iphone Xr. always not fullscreen or with black borders.

Ipad was no problem because it has the same size in 2nd Gen and 3rd gen... but my app  starts in the simulator when I choose e.g. iPhone Xs Max without fullscreen.

I tried sth on deployment target in Xcode but it always is the same result. a big black border on the bottom and footer (it's not fullscreen) but only on the 3rd generation iPad and iPhone Simulator :/

Comment: What's your viewport config?

Comment: So you want to take screenshot of fullscreen (Without black border at top and bottom)...right ?

Comment: Exactly, i found the answer here , thank you for your help !https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing black bars at the top and bottom of the iPhone X Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator)