# How to hide status bar in ios13 in cocos-2dx

Tags: c++, objective-c, statusbar, ios13, cocos2d-x-3.0

I was using

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

in info.plist file to hide status bar for ios. Also in my RootViewController.mm is

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
{
   return YES;
}
```

to fix hiding status bar on ios7. 
Everything worked fine untill I tried this code on ios13. At ios13 status bar does not hide anymore. **Does anybody know how to hide status bar for ios13?**
I also tried to add

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

in info.plist, but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason for that.
my project was missing launchscreen storyboard.
Adding launchscreen storyboard [Seeing black bars at the top and bottom of the iPhone X Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator) and hiding safe area https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89037 and setting launch screen file in general settings allowed to hide status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudle View controller-based status bar appearance set is true

```
   <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/> 

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

or

```
   <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/> 

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but nothing seemed to change.

I also tried this issue on pure 3.17.1 cocos-2dx demo project. The apps layout covers all screen, so status bar is not visible. 
I tried to compare parametrs -`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width` and [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height in AppController.mm in both projects, and I`ve got the following results:
My prjoject: width 320, height 568,
Demo project: width 812, height 375.
I guess smth is wrong with screen width and height, but I did not find how to change them, maybe because I am new to ios development.
Any ideas?